# Debug Assertation Failed c >= -1 && c <= 255

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c-strings

I am having a difficult time understanding this runtime error with my code. This was an assignment for my class that I thought would be easy, but something strange is gong on. I have posted my code below.

The prompt for this assignment was to create a program that asks the user to enter to enter some words, then it should output how many words there are. I have had a friend run the program and it worked, however, whenever I try to run it I get this runtime error. 
[ https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhqbe.jpg ]

Please keep in mind that I am a beginner at C++ and programming in general, so I won't be able to understand very technical responses. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int wordCounter(char *);

int main()
{
    char *stringArray = nullptr;
    stringArray = new char[120];

    cout << "Please enter a saying or a phrase that has more than one word: " << endl;
    cin.getline(stringArray, 120);

    int words = wordCounter(stringArray);
    cout << "Your statement contains " << words << " words." << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int wordCounter(char *stringTest)
{
    char characterToTest;
    int numberOfWords = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < 120; i++)
    {
        characterToTest = *(stringTest + i);
        if (isspace(characterToTest) && i != 120)
        {
            char characterToTestTemp = *(stringTest + (i + 1));
            if (isalnum(characterToTestTemp))
            {
                numberOfWords++;
            }
        }
    }
    return numberOfWords;
}
```

Comment: You're not stopping at the actual input length, therefore you're processing indeterminate garbage paste the length of the input string.

Comment: When I ran your code on my c++, I changed `nullptr` to `NULL` ( I'm using older version, so no `nullptr` ) and my program compiled without any problem but the number of words is wrong, If I enter 3 words, the output gives 2 words and if I enter 20 words, the output gives 19 words.

Comment: Your code has multiple issues. Failing to test fro the end of the actual line that was input (rather than the end of the buffer) is one. Waiting a for a first space character before trying to recognise any words is another (which is why you are not counting the first word).

Comment: @ArunA.S Undefined behaviour can manifest in different ways. Your compiler either has char as unsigned or doesn't check what value is passed to is space etc, or is zero initialising the buffer.

Comment: @Alan Stokes, I don't understand what you're saying ( I'm not that smart, still a newbie ). What I meant is that when I compiled @Dranslin's code, It showed error due to `nullptr`. My compiler is gcc 4.8.0 ( Devc++ ), so I changed the `nullptr` to `NULL` and the program compiled and gave output ( although the number of words always seemed to be 1 less than the number I typed ). Please explain what you meant ( I did not get any Undefined behaviour ).

Comment: @ArunA.S The program reads beyond the end of the string, and does other bad things (described in the answers). But C++ didn't require to give you an error message; it just says the behaviour is undefined, so the program can do anything. The OP was lucky enough to get an error message. The fact that you didn't, but got the wrong answer, is also allowed.

Answer (score 5):

`isspace` and friends are surprisingly hard to call correctly. Specifically you can't safely pass a `char` to them, because `char` values can be negative and that is not allowed, as the error message says.

You should cast to `unsigned char` to be safe:

```
isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(characterToTest))
```

That isn't the main problem here, you need to fix the overrun first, but it's part of why you're getting the error message.

Answer (score 4):

You're not stopping at the termination of the input string, instead marching into non-input, indeterminate buffer data left at the tail end of our input buffer.

This is what you're likely trying to do:

```
int wordCounter(const char *str)
{
    int numberOfWords = 0;
    while (*str)
    {
        // skip any leading whitespace
        while (*str && isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(*str)))
            ++str;

        // if we're still on string data, we have another word
        if (*str)
        {
            // skip everything up to more whitespace
            while (*str && !isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(*str)))
                ++str;

            // and count the word
            ++numberOfWords;
        }
    }
    return numberOfWords;
}
```

Or something similar. Additional handling may need to be applied to account for punctuation, etc. This stops as soon as you reach the terminator of the input string.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your wordcount function always process 120 characters regardless of the length of the input string really read. So your are reading past the end of the string and dealing with uninitialized memory.

Microsoft docyumentation reads "The behavior of _isctype and _isctype_l is undefined if c is not EOF or in the range 0 through 0xFF, inclusive. When a debug CRT library is used and c is not one of these values, the functions raise an assertion."

That's the reason for the assertion.

C strings are zero-terminated, you must test that condition into your loop.

```
int wordCounter(char *stringTest)
{
    char characterToTest;
    int numberOfWords = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 120; i++)
    {
        characterToTest = *(stringTest + i);
        if (characterToTest == 0)  
            break; // <-- exit the loop at the end of the string
        if (isspace(characterToTest) && i != 120)
        {
            char characterToTestTemp = *(stringTest + (i + 1));
            if (isalnum(characterToTestTemp))
            {
                numberOfWords++;
            }
        }
    }
    return numberOfWords;
}
```

you might have other logical bugs in your counting function, like not counting the first word.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. Reading on this (and I do realize that I have logical errors that don't account for if a user enters nothing and submits it, it will still print 1), I was able to come up with a slightly different approach to this.

Here is the revised code.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int wordCounter(char *, int);

int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter a saying or a phrase that has more than one word: " << endl;

    string testString;
    getline(cin, testString);

    int stringLength = testString.length();

    char *stringArray = nullptr;
    stringArray = new char[stringLength];

    strcpy(stringArray, testString.c_str());

    int words = wordCounter(stringArray, stringLength);
    cout << "Your statement contains " << words << " words." << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int wordCounter(char *stringTest, int length)
{
    char characterToTest;
    int numberOfWords = 1;
    for (int i=0; i < length; i++)
    {

            characterToTest = *(stringTest + i);

            if (isspace(characterToTest) && (i != length))
            {

                    char characterToTestTemp = *(stringTest + (i + 1));
                    if (isalnum(characterToTestTemp))
                    {
                            numberOfWords++;
                    }
            }
    }
    return numberOfWords;
}
```

Comment: int stringLength = testString.length();
 char *stringArray = new char[stringLength]; 
 strcpy(stringArray, testString.c_str());

    you create an array of N bytes, and then you copy N+1 bytes into it (strcpy terminates its copy with an extra \0 byte). This is named "a buffer overflow mistake".