# Getting Error Debug Assertion Failed: Expression c >= -1 && c <= 255

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, c++14

I have following code which works well on my ubuntu system:

```
#include <algorithm>
// ... other functions
bool IsHexPrefixed(const std::string& input) {
    return input.substr(0, 2) == "0x";
}

std::string StripHexPrefix(const std::string& input) {
    return IsHexPrefixed(input) ? input.substr(2, input.length()) : input;
}

bool IsHexString(const std::string& input) {
    std::string stripped_string_ = StripHexPrefix(input);
    return std::all_of(stripped_string_.begin(), stripped_string_.end(), ::isxdigit);
}
// ... some other functions
```

On Windows 10 via `cmd`, `VSCode`, and `Visual Studio 2019` I get pop-up mentioning the Debug Assertion Error on Windows as well as Visual Studio 2019.

[image]

The line on which this error is coming is `std::all_of()` function call in `IsHexString()` function.

I tried to use exceptions and find out where the exception is coming, but no solution is found yet. I also tried to use Breakpoint but that is also not helping to get the cause.

What could be the reason for this error?

**EDIT:**
The string that I passed to `IsHexString()` function is `000002C479F17CC0`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes I am using the latest version of VS2019. The error is coming even if I build it using VSCode and cmd. The string that I passed is mentioned in my edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Debug Assertation Failed c >= -1 && c <= 255](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28513332/debug-assertation-failed-c-1-c-255). Also your stripped_string_ doesn't contain what you think it contains (probably contains garbage, BOM, or alike).

Comment: @srahul07 please, provide MCVE. What does StripHexPrefix do?

Comment: @DanM. I have added the StripHexPrefix function. It checks if there is hex prefix, if it is it will remove it.

Comment: @rustyx I checked the link you have mentioned. Both are completely different scenarios. Also, I checked value returned by `stripped_string_` variable and it is `Ç` this character.

Comment: `Ç` is a sequence of `char`s. One of them is `0xc7` (utf-16) or you have `0xc3 0x87` (utf-8) which converted to `char` is `< -1` which makes `isxdigit`s assertion kick in as @DanM. says in his answer. Did you try his solution?

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes it did work. But I feel like it might cause issues if the value is not representable in 1 byte.

Comment: @srahul07 Indeed it may. `isxdigit` may report a false positive if you have a utf `char` sequence containing `[0-9a-fA-F]`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo then should I consider using boost::regex instead for this? Or what else will you advise on this?

Comment: @srahul07 generally, it could, as C++ doesn't really handle non-ASCII chars well, but for this specific function it doesn't matter as long as you use utf8. The hex chars are the same single-byte ASCII.

Comment: @TedLyngmo utf sequence containing `[0-9a-fA-F]` is just an ASCII sequence, so there is no problem there.

Comment: @DanM. I was thinking that if he's using unicode characters outside the ASCII range there may be collisions in the unicode representation (utf8/16) with the ASCII characters in the range `[0-9a-fA-F]` - but it was a long time since I fiddled with utf so I don't remember if such collisions exist.

Comment: @DanM.thanks for the explanation. As of now, I will keep it as you have mentioned, as per the current requirement it will be `utf8` character always. But it may change in the future.

Comment: @TedLyngmo actually in my case, every input will be converted to Hex always before doing any processing, so, @DanM is right. I have written my own converters but now I am planning to use `boost::hex` and `boost::unhex` to avoid any of the complications. I hope that should be fine.

Comment: @TedLyngmo since the function checks that ALL characters are hex, and ALL hex characters are ASCII, it also checks that ALL characters are ASCII, i.e. it'll return false on any non-ASCII (and non-hex) char, which includes non-ASCII utf characters.

Comment: @DanM. True, I didn't think of it that way :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is just what the assertion says. `isxdigit` is undefined if it's argument is not represented as `unsigned char` or `EOF`(see notes [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isxdigit)).
Since it takes an `int` argument, it's highly likely your string contains chars in range `129-255` (probably by containing non-ASCII text), so they get promoted to negative integer numbers.

The linked cppreference page also has a workaround to avoid promotion issues that you could apply to you case:

```
std::all_of(stripped_string_.begin(), stripped_string_.end(),
            [](unsigned char c){ return std::isxdigit(c); });
```

Another possibility is that `StripHexPrefix` function corrupts your string causing the problem above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it helped. But I feel if the character is more than 1 byte sized then this will cause issues. So, Is it advisable to use `isdigit` and `isxdigit` functions in algorithms like in my code, because I read the link you share there also it is mentioned that ` they should not be directly used with standard algorithms`. So, should I look for some other solution for the same like regex may be?